# Access violation writing location error using arrays in x86 assembly c++

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

I am trying to update a specific index in array using x86. I am getting an error from Visual Studio "Access violation writing location..." error on the line: `mov [ebx+ecx], eax`.
What can I do to fix this.

Sample code:

```
int main() {

   float price[ ] = { 22.1, 34.44, 567.33, 2.45 };
   float newPrice = 32.55;
   int newPriceIndex = 1; // replace 34.44 with 32.55


   __asm {
      mov eax, newPrice
      mov ebx, price
      mov ecx, newPriceIndex
      mov [ebx+ecx], eax
   }

   cout << "price[newPriceIndex] = " << price[newPriceIndex]; //should show 32.55

   return 0

}
```

Comment: Forget the assembly for the moment.   What is the value of `&price[1]`?  Now what is the value of `[ebx+ecx]`?  Do they match?  That should have been the first thing you should have done, and that is to verify if what you are writing to is the actual address it should be.

Answer (score 2):

`mov ebx, price` loads the value from memory, not a pointer, like usual for MASM syntax with `mov reg, symbol`.  **It's an array object, not a pointer, and (I think) doesn't "decay" to a pointer when used this way**.

There isn't a pointer to that array sitting anywhere in memory you can load with `mov`, because that's not how C arrays work.

**Use a debugger to see the register value.**  Also, look at the compiler-generated assembly, using disassembly-view in your debugger.  That way you can see that it assembled to `mov ebx, [ebp + something]`, loading `price[0]`.

Writing asm (especially inline asm) without a debugger is like trying to build a robot blindfolded; it's a waste of your time and everyone else's.

---

`mov [price + ecx*4], eax` might possibly work, if MSVC will compile that into an `[ebp + constant + ecx*4]` addressing mode for you.

If not **use `lea ebx, [price]` instead of MOV to get the address**.  (And still scale your index because elements are 4 bytes long.  Otherwise you're doing a 4-byte store at a 1-byte offset that partially overlaps two `float` elements of `price[]`.)